# looking for science fiction short story about boy and friends who jump through planet gates to watch star explosions

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, young-adult, soft-sci-fi

This story is relatively new. It's short probably from one of the most known sci/fi magazines (*Asimov*, *Analog*, *The magazine of fantasy and science fiction*, *Clarkesworld*) I just read it earlier this year or maybe late last year. It's about a kid in high school who leaves a planet with his mom to the Moon or some other off-Earth settlement. At this juncture in the story, we don't yet know the reason why they are leaving their old home.  He starts at a new school and to fit in, he joins with this group of kids that use some kind of jumper that lets them go from planet to planet racing past police officers that regulate the use of planetary jump gates to eventually land in a room and watch stars blow up and take civilized populated planets with them. Because they are jumping through space to further reaches in the universe they are also jumping through time. Eventually, as the story ends, he realizes that his mother and he didn't simply leave his father and resettle somewhere else but that he just watched his homeworld and his dad blow up when the sun went supernova.

Comment: What is *SF&F*? What are the kid and his mom fleeing from? The law? Bill collectors? Or did you leave out some element of the story?

Comment: What are "custom cops"?

Comment: @user114111 SF&F should be the magazine of Fantasy and Science Fiction.  I never heard of Clarkesworld before and had to look it up.

Comment: They have jump gates, but let populated planets get destroyed? That's weird!

Comment: people and families who couldn't afford a ticket to leave the planet stayed, or maybe some decided to stay. when the kid was jumping through the gates it was illegal, like a subway jumper getting a free ride